# "lastModifiedDateTime" filter in SharePoint returns "BadRequest" error

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, microsoft-graph

I want to list all the sites which have been modified after the last time when I query the API. I wanted to use Microsoft Delta query but seems like it is not supported for SharePoint sites([documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#supported-resources)). I wanted to use "lastModifiedDateTime" field which is returned when we make a call to list of sites but it returns error. Now I am trying to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2020-06-16T11:55:20.8954082Z'` this to list sites which got modified after a certain timestamp but this is returning following error. I am not sure what is going wrong

```
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid filter clause",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-16T12:01:28",
      "request-id": "a0e05240-5487-4d7c-95c2-a7edff633e39"
    }
  }
}
```

Following is a snippet of response when I list sites `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites`

```
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2020-02-12T09:26:47Z",
            "id": "abc.sharepoint.com,f35e3f05-0710-4b13-93c6-84faa980df31,aa4b6b35-95e1-4578-aa95-a08c9aa7ef82",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-06-16T11:55:20.8016529Z",
            "name": "Communication site",
            "displayName": "Communication site",
            "webUrl": "https://abc.sharepoint.com/",
            "sharepointIds": {
                "siteId": "f35e3f05-0710-4b13-93c6-84faa980df31",
                "siteUrl": "https://abc.sharepoint.com/",
                "tenantId": "eda49d10-1ba9-42fa-a58c-b5dd47946110",
                "webId": "aa4b6b35-95e1-4578-aa95-a08c9aa7ef82"
            },
            "siteCollection": {
                "hostname": "abc.sharepoint.com"
            },
            "root": {}
        },
```

Comment: If think `$filter` is not yet supported for `sites` endpoints, atleast not in `v1.0`.

Comment: Is there a way to get modified, deleted, newly created sites?

Comment: something like https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request